# jQuery in German text

Tags: jquery

I am manipulating German text in jQuery.

1. Maßnahme
2. Text

Now I need to check these texts in my switch case:

```
switch(compare){
    case 'Text':
        alert("Text");break;
    case 'Maßnahme':
        alert("Welcome");break;
    default:;
}
```

Is there equivalent Unicode to check the German text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a supplement to [kgiannakakis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568608/jquery-in-german-text/568628#568628):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

If you use utf-8, be sure to **save your files as UTF-8 encoded**. Check the settings of your (text) editor.

Answer (score 1):

Save your file in UTF8 encoding and the switch case should work.

Add the following in the head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and make your server return content in UTF8.